# Javascript regex format number

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I used this https://github.com/mtyugaev/jquery-number-divider
for formating number .
my problem is how to setup the regex only accept number or negative number.
example : - 1,000 or 1,000
and reject if user input alphabet.

i try change this code : delimiterRegExp: /[.,\s]/g
but not work to block alphabet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
/^-?([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1][0][0][0]|)?$/
```

Comment: not work. i cann't type number

Comment: @Prinsip check this code



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
const regex = /^-?([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1][0][0][0]|)?$/;
const str = `-1001`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>